# Using VBA to print multiple invoices in a page, and print invoices for select customers only

Tags: excel, vba

Invoice Template Image

[image: Invoice Template Image]

I'm printing invoices in Excel using the template above, where the details of the templates are pulled from a worksheet with each row containing the particulars of a single invoice.

Each page has two invoices, and I want to set it up such that I can print the invoices of only a particular customer at a time. The customer name is the `wks1.Cells(i, 6).Value`.

I've tried using simple `If` statements within the `For` loop, but no matter what I do, only the first invoice on the page is printed with the relevant customer. The second invoice is empty.

Using a custom filter and selecting only the customer I want to print invoices for doesn't help, because the code processes each row, regardless of the filter. I don't mind the name of the customer being hardcoded into the VBA.

I just want both the invoices on the page to be sequentially printed, based on the `wks1.Cells(i, 6).Value` value.

Here is my code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

// Data Source
Set wks1 = Sheets("Data")
// Invoice Template
Set wks2 = Sheets("Template")

Dim i As Integer

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    // Make a temporary working copy
    wks2.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "wks3"

    Set wks3 = Sheets("wks3")

    // Fill the details for the first invoice in the page

    wks3.Range("C3").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    wks3.Range("C5").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    wks3.Range("F14").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 3).Value & " days at " & ChrW(&H20B9) & " " & wks1.Cells(i, 4).Value & " per day "
    wks3.Range("C7").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 5).Text
    wks3.Range("I18").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 5).Text
    // wks1.Cells(i, 6).Value = Customer Name
    wks3.Range("C9").Value = " " & wks1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    wks3.Range("C12").Value = " " & wks1.Cells(i, 7).Value
    wks3.Range("C14").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    wks3.Range("C16").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    wks3.Range("C18").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    wks3.Range("D21").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 11).Value

    // Increment "i" to process the next row in the Data Source worksheet
    i = i + 1

    // Fill the details for the second invoice in the page

    wks3.Range("C27").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    wks3.Range("C29").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    wks3.Range("F38").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 3).Value & " days at " & ChrW(&H20B9) & " " & wks1.Cells(i, 4).Value & " per day "
    wks3.Range("C31").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 5).Text
    wks3.Range("I42").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 5).Text
    // wks1.Cells(i, 6).Value = Customer Name
    wks3.Range("C33").Value = " " & wks1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    wks3.Range("C36").Value = " " & wks1.Cells(i, 7).Value
    wks3.Range("C38").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    wks3.Range("C40").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    wks3.Range("C42").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    wks3.Range("D45").Value = wks1.Cells(i, 11).Value

    // Save temporary working sheet as PDF
    wks3.Range("A1:L48").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdf\" & wks1.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value & "-" & wks1.Cells(i, 1).Value

    // Delete temporary working sheet after PDF is saved
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wks3.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    wks1.Activate

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. can u show an example of wks1 ?

Answer (score 0):

there is another approach to fill the 2nd voucher without VBA. Just use "=" and cell number in the related cell of 2nd voucher.